# D3.js Basic Chart Drawing Example not displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to Javascript and would like to use the D3 library to visualize my data online.

I have found many examples on the web about drawing a simple bar chart from an array of data. The following example doesn't work however and it just returns a blank web page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <style>

       .chart div {
       font: 10px sans-serif;
       background-color: steelblue;
       text-align: right;
       padding: 3px;
       margin: 1px;
       color: white;
     }

   </style>
  <div class="chart"></div>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 <script> 
    var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];  

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
      .range([0, 420]);
    d3.select(".chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("div")
      .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
   </script>
```

Could this be a problem with the source script (http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js) or maybe the browser? 
Any help would be more than appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a d3 version **3** method while loading d3 version **4** library.  Simply replace:

```
d3.scale.linear()
```

With:

```
d3.scaleLinear()
```

---

From the [changes docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> ...If you don’t care about modularity, you can mostly ignore this
>   change and keep using the default bundle. However, there is one
>   unavoidable consequence of adopting ES6 modules: every symbol in D3
>   4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x. For example, d3.scale.linear is now d3.scaleLinear...

---

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
  var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);
  d3.select(".chart")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) {
      return x(d) + "px";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
</script>
```